# Stack build fails due to missing dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I am trying to make something like acme-everything for stackage called [`ghci-all`](https://github.com/anfelor/ghci-all), e. g.  a stack project, where `stack ghci` gives you access to all of stackage. I added all the packages in the latest snashot to my .cabal file, and after working through all the foreign dependencies, I got the strange error:

```
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3: At least the following dependencies
are missing:
Ebnf2ps -any,
TaxonomyTools -any,
YampaSynth -any,
alex -any,
angel -any,
bumper -any,
c2hs -any,
cabal-install -any,
cabal-rpm -any,
cabal-sort -any,
cabal-src -any,
calculator -any,
clash-ghc -any,
clckwrks-cli -any,
gipeda -any,
git-fmt -any,
gtk2hs-buildtools -any,
hackage-whatsnew -any,
haddocset -any,
happy -any,
hdevtools -any,
hledger-interest -any,
hledger-ui -any,
hopenpgp-tools -any,
hspec-setup -any,
ip6addr -any,
lentil -any,
lhs2tex -any,
moesocks -any,
mole -any,
resolve-trivial-conflicts -any,
sandman -any,
servius -any,
shelltestrunner -any,
skeletons -any,
tellbot -any,
tls-debug -any,
tttool -any,
yackage -any,
yesod-bin -any
```

These dependencies are listed in the file though (and should have been installed). Did I miss something important?

Comment: This seems like it could be an issue arising from a misconfigured `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @JulesMazur: Under user `me`:
/home/me/.local/bin:/home/me/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/me/.cabal/bin:/home/me/.local/bin:/home/me/bin

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your repo. What's the command you got that error for? What's your `stack --version`? BTW you added your `.stack-work` to your repo…

Comment: @sjakobi The command is `stack build`, the version is 1.0.4.3, Git revision db1afb275ebd64016e8ef0db122f0f03da9e5906 (3242 commits) x86_64

Comment: @sjakobi, I wanted to publish the repo, when I was done, but now.., anyway: [Alex](https://github.com/anfelor/ghci-all/blob/master/.stack-work/logs/alex-3.1.7.log) for example compiled without errors, but is in the list above.

Comment: Can you retry with the HEAD version of stack: `stack upgrade --git`? If that doesn't help, please open an issue at https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a confusing error message from Cabal. You're not able to add an executable only package to build-depends. You'll need to filter out projects that do not have a library.